# Problema com aspas na sintaxe de consulta no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma classe, e dentro dessa classe, tenho uma função pra atualizar um dado no banco de dados MySQL. Segue a função:

```
public function set_detail($id, $detail, $value) {
  $query = "UPDATE `contacts` SET $detail = '$value' WHERE `contact`.`id` = $id";
  if (parent::do_sql($query)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Até aí, tudo bem. Mas o problema está na variável `'$value'`. Se o valor recebido via `$_POST` for `NULL`, `'$value'` recebe uma string vazia `''` e assim é enviado ao banco de dados.

Presumi que isso aconteça por causa das aspas simples em volta da variável. Por isso retirei as aspas e ao tentar realizar a consulta novamente, me aparece o erro de sintaxe:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `contacts`.`id` = 0000000839'
```

Presumi também que tenha sido por retirar as aspas. Porém já escrevi consultas no MySQL sem aspas e funcionaram normalmente.

O que não quero é deixar strings vazias no banco de dados. Como resolver isso? Qual a maneira correta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você tira o aspas simples de `SET $detail = '$value' WHERE...` e `$value` for nulo ou vazio, ele causa esse erro por que o SQL será montado assim `SET $detail = WHERE...`.

A forma mais simples para resolver esse problema é tratar quando `$value` for nulo ou vazio usando a função [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php).

O código ficaria assim:

```
if(empty($value)){
    // Código que lida quando for nulo ou vazio.
    // Você pode colocar um simples return false, ou lançar um throw.
    // Ou colocar setar um valor padrão para $value.
}
```

Comment: Entendo... Mas se executar a consulta direto no phpMyAdmin, o SQL fica assim: `UPDATE 'contacts' SET 'phone' = NULL WHERE 'contacts'.'id' = 0000000839`. Como fazer isso na função?

Comment: Se você quer dessa forma, basta setar o valor de `$value` dentro do `if` por "NULL", e utilizar a query da mesma forma como estava antes.

Comment: Usei essa mesma lógica, mas dentro da função pra montar a consulta. Ficou assim: `if (empty($value) || $value == "") { $query = "UPDATE 'contacts' SET $detail = NULL WHERE 'contacts'.'id' = $id"; } else { $query = "UPDATE 'contacts_business' SET $detail = '$value' WHERE 'contacts_business'.'id' = $id"; }`

Comment: Assim mesmo. Só um adendo, não precisa fazer a comparação de `$value == ""` pois a própria função já faz essa verificação. Deixo aqui também [uma outra solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4620409/8741188) com a mesma pergunta só que feita em inglês.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a melhor maneira de resolver isso é definindo as aspas da variável apenas se ela não estiver vazia. Além disso, o `null` tem de ser string para que o termo "null" apareça no seu código SQL.

```html
public function set_detail($id, $detail, $value) {
 if(!empty($value)){
  $value = "'".$value."'";
 }
 else{
    $value = "NULL";
   }


 $query = "UPDATE contacts SET ".$detail." = ".$value." WHERE contact.id = ".$id;
 if (parent::do_sql($query)) {
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}
```